# Access csv data from internet with c# and System.Net.Http

Tags: c#, system.net

I am trying to download historical time series from Yahoo! Finance (I have the same issue with other sites). I have embedded the url address in a function to get a csv file. I am using System.Net and I am really not familiar with the protocols.

The address I am seeking is:

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?&period1=1662422400&period2=1693958400&interval=1d&ignore=.csv&events=history

It works well when I directly use it in my internet navigator: the csv file is correctly downloaded.

Now, I am trying to call it through the following routine:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace Space
{
    public class HistData
    {
        private WebClient connector;

        public string GetData(string address)
        {
            string csvData = null;
            using (connector = new WebClient())
            {
                using (Stream strm = connector.OpenRead(address))
                {
                    using (StreamReader strd = new StreamReader(strm))
                    {
                        csvData = strd.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            return csvData;
        }
    }
}
```

I have an exception on the statement

```
connector.OpenRead(address)
```

that says 'connector.OpenRead(address)' threw an exception of type 'System.Net.WebException': "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send".

The inner exception gives me the message: "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream".

Is there a way to bypass or sort out this problem?

---

**Addendum**

---

Following the comments, I moved to Windows 10 and VS 2015.

I changed the code to this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Space
{
    public class HistData
    {
        private static string address1 ="https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AAPL?&period1=1694563200&period2=1694736000&interval=1d&ignore=.csv&events=history";
        private static string address2 ="https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/AAPL/downloaddatapartial?&startdate=8/15/2023&enddate=9/15/2023&frequency=p1d&csvdownload=true";
        
        private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        private static string csvData;

        public string GetCsvData(string address)
        {
            Task<bool> awaiter = GetCsvData(address);
            if (awaiter.Result)
            {
                return csvData;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public async Task<bool> GetCsvData(string address)
        {
            if (address != null && address != "")
            {
                using (client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (Stream strm = await client.GetStreamAsync(address))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader strd = new StreamReader(strm))
                        {
                            csvData = strd.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I request the data from the internet browser for both Yahoo! Finance and Market Watch addresses, I get the expected csv file.

If I run the request for Yahoo! Finance under the routine, it still works. However, if I run the request for Market Watch under the routine, it fails. I have the following exceptions.

```
"System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.\r\n
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.\r\n
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n
   at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---<---\r\n"
```

I have the same question as before: is there a way to prevent or circumvent this sort of problem?

Comment: Note this remark in the the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-7.0) "We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class"

Comment: Post the actual *full* exception text, not just parts of the messages. Does a nested inner exception complain about SSL perhaps? All major services use TLS 1.2 nowadays, which works automatically in all *supported* .NET and Windows versions, ie .NET Framework 4.6.2 and later, and Windows 10 and later. Older Windows versions required patching to enable TLS 1.2. Older .NET versions didn't enable TLS 1.2 by default

Comment: Many thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos. Unfortunately, I am running VS 9.0 on XP and the only security protocols that are available are Ssl3 and Tls.

Comment: Many thanks @JonasH. Unfortunately, I am running VS 9.0 on XP and no System.Net.Http.HttpClient class is available there either.

Comment: `on XP` In that case you can't connect to any web service, no matter what library you use. The OS itself didn't support TLS 1.2 or any  of the .NET Frameworks that work with it - .NET Framework 4.0 was the last version to support XP.

Comment: wow, I admire your bravery/foolishness, running an internet connected XP computer in 2023. And kind of amazed anything works at all, given that most protocols have been updated.  I would expect all kinds of problems using https due to certificates and/or CAs being out of date. The only real solution here is to use a modern platform.

Comment: Microsoft itself didn't issue any patches to enable TLS 1.2 on Windows XP. AFAIK Windows 7 was the first version to support TLS 1.2, even with patching. Windows XP reached End Of Life in 2014, 9 years ago.